# How to Compare between two rows of same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a query which will compare data's of single column

So i have a table with structure like

```
S.no  **SampleNo** 
100        0
 A         13
 B         25
 C         38
```

So now the end user passes some random sample number e.g. 11.12.
Now i need to compare this passed number with the sampleNo Column.
Now in this Scenario 11.12 Comes Between 0 and 13 so i need to show A as an output to the query.

I hope you understood the question.

I need to write a query like

**get the S.no where passedValue >0 and <=13. And the output should be 100**

Likewise if a user passes 24 as an input then my query should become like
**get the S.no where passedValue > 13 and  <=25. And the output should be A**

Looking forward to your solution and thanks in advance for helping..

Comment: Your question is incomplete. What is the expected result when the input is 100? And when the input is -1?

Comment: The input will be within the range of what the sampling number is.. So the user has to pass the input within the range for possible comparison.

Answer (score 1):

This query will return the row with the smallest SampleNo larger than passedValue.

```
select *
from demo1 
where passedValue <= SampleNo
order by SampleNo
limit 1
```

Executes with literal for passed value as:

```
SQL>select *
SQL&from demo1 
SQL&where 11.12 <= SampleNo
SQL&order by SampleNo
SQL&fetch first 1 row only;
sno           sampleno
========== ===========
A                   13

                  1 row found
```

And with parameter for first value as:

```
SQL>create table demo1 (sno varchar(10), sampleno int);
SQL>insert into demo1 values ('100',0);
SQL>insert into demo1 values ('A',13);
SQL>insert into demo1 values ('B',25);
SQL>insert into demo1 values ('C',38);
SQL>select *
SQL&from demo1 
SQL&where :passedValue <= SampleNo
SQL&order by SampleNo
SQL&fetch first 1 row only;
passedValue:11.12
sno           sampleno
========== ===========
A                   13

                  1 row found
```

Note that I'm not using MySQL, so instead of `LIMIT` I have ANSI SQL's `FETCH FIRST`, but that doesn't matter here.

Comment: select *
from demo1
where SampleNo < 11.12
order by SampleNo desc
limit 1. I tried this query and it is somwhat working but i am getting wrong result

Comment: you've got your operator the wrong way round ;-) it should be where 11.12 < SampleNo

Comment: @Roy, as Gallus said, it should be `where 11.12 <= SampleNo`.

Comment: @Roy, take a look at my two examples.

Comment: Your query is almost correct. But still i am not getting the result that i intend to.

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT T1.S.no FROM Your_tableName T1 WHERE T1.SampleNo = (
   SELECT MAX(T2.SampleNo) FROM Your_tableName T2 WHERE T2.SampleNo BETWEEN @val1 AND @val2 );
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Mansoor but user won't pass val1 and val2.

Comment: Than where you get value from 11 and 12

Comment: it is number with decimal .ie 11.12

Comment: I need to compare the passedValue with next and previous value

Comment: Do you pass only 11.12 or 13

Comment: I only pass 11.12

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.S.no FROM Your_tableName a WHERE a.SampleNo = 
(
   SELECT MAX(b.SampleNo) FROM Your_tableName b WHERE b.SampleNo > @Passval
);
```

Comment: Hi Husen; your code might be correct, but with some context it would make a better answer; for example, you could explain how and why this proposed change would resolve the questioner's problem, perhaps including a link to the relevant documentation. That would make it more useful to them, and also more useful to other site readers who are looking for solutions to similar problems.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Husen but the query is giving me wrong results

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `S.no` FROM your_table
WHERE @passed_value < `SampleNo`
ORDER BY `SampleNo` ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Be careful with your table field names with dots in it (S.no). Quote them using backticks to avoid problems. Or consider renaming them.

Regarding this point: there're not 'official' MySql naming conventions. But there are some recomendations that may be interesting to stick to:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/coding-style.html

http://www.sqlstyle.guide/#general-1

In there, you can find a recomendation about general naming: "Only use letters, numbers and underscores in names." ...it's not a strict rule.